# aws ec2 cli + jq exclude results

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli, jq

I'm writing a bash script that needs to get the private ips of all instances where describe-instances does not return platform=>windows, and store them in an array $ips

This script works so far (just getting the private ips)

```
 ips=$(aws ec2 describe-instances --region $r --filters "Name=tag:Name,Values=*$c*" | jq '.Reservations[].Instances[].NetworkInterfaces[].PrivateIpAddress')
```

but what I can't figure out is how to exclude windows servers (or, conversely, only include non-windows servers)

Here's what I've tried

```
--filters "Name=tag:Name,Values=*$c*" "Name=platform,Values="
--filters "Name=tag:Name,Values=*$c*" "Name=platform,Values=null"
--filters "Name=tag:Name,Values=*$c*" "Name=platform,Values=NULL"
```

I've also tried doing it on the jq side of the pipe, but my attempts were ridiculous and I will not publish them here. I did find out you cannot do more than two filters on that side (unless I messed that up too)

Any ideas?

Comment: What does the json look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use AWS so I don't have much to go on but based off of the [`describe-instances`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-instances.html) reference, I think this filter should work.

```
.Reservations[].Instances |
    map(select(.Platform != "Windows") | .NetworkInterfaces[].PrivateIpAddress)
```

Comment: Got 'em coach! I had to switch the == to != since I'm trying to exclude windows results, but it worked!